# Elasticsearch. Переполнение кучи (ошибка heap is over 85%)

Tags: elasticsearch

Всем привет.

Zabbix выдает такое предупреждение:

> Problem started at 20:08:27 on 2022.09.28 Problem name: Elasticsearch
> Node Heap is over 85% on data_1 Host: CGISPT01 Severity: High
> Operational data: 88 % Original problem ID: 149494

В чем причина сообщения, насколько это критично и как можно исправить? Появляется предупреждение не часто, может раз в полторы-две недели.

Answer (score 0):

Точных причин сработок установить не удалось, но частично проблему решил отключением файлов подкачки из этой статьи. После этого ошибки почти перестали появляться.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration-memory.html